# How to display actual image based on file name in sqlite database

Tags: android, image, sqlite, imageview, android-imageview

I have a local sqlite database file that looks something like this…

```
_ID | Color_Name | Image_Name  
1   | Red        | red.png  
2   | Blue       | blue.png  
3   | Green      | green.png  
Etc.
```

The Image_Name column of the database contains ONLY the file name, NOT the image itself.  All images are stored locally in the res/drawable-mdpi directory.

The goal is to have a list that displays the color name and the associated image for that color from the database. For example, the list would look something like this [the plus sign below represents an actual .png image]…

```
____________________________________________

Red (text only on this line)  
+ (actual red.png image on this line)  
____________________________________________

Blue (text only on this line)  
+ (actual blue.png image on this line)  
____________________________________________

Etc.
```

I can get the color name to display, but I can't figure out how to get the image itself to display. The relevant portion of code for displaying the name is below…

```
static class ColorHolder {
    private TextView name=null;

     ColorHolder(View row) {             
        name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.colorName);

        }
           void populateFrom(Cursor c, ColortHelper r) {

               name.setText(r.getName(c)) ;
          }
}
```

The relevant portion of the xml file for BOTH the name & image is below…

```
<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
android:id="@+id/colorName"/>

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/ImageView00"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:src="@drawable/image1" <!--[NOTE: THIS DEFAULT IMAGE FILE SHOULD BE REPLACED ON THE FLY W/THE CORRECT IMAGE FILE FOR EACH RECORD]-->
  >
```

None of the other questions I found were helpful in resolving this issue for me. Could someone please help me get this figured out? I would be happy for any help, but it would be especially helpful if you could use my ACTUAL file names / paths / variables / ID's / etc. (which are given above) in your explanation so that I could most easily follow & understand your response. Pointing me to tutorials may not be helpful as I have already looked at a lot of material but didn't get this resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Resources.getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Also you don't need to store the resource image name ... just name them the same as the color (as you already have done), just make sure as I show here that they are lower case

To use your example:

```
void populateFrom(Cursor c, ColorHelper r) {

    //get the color name from your database (only once)

    String strColor = r.getName(c);

    // set the text on your TextView as before

    TextView clrName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView00);
    clrName.setText(strColor);

    // get the resource ID - note "name" without extension

    int resourceID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(strColor.toLower(),
            "drawable", context.getPackageName());

    //get a reference to your imageview and set the image

    ImageView clrImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView00);
    clrImage.setImageResource(resourceID);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried plugging this in and it won't compile. It says 'context cannot be resolved' and 'imageview cannot be resolved' (got the same message when I tried imageView). Maybe I put this in the wrong place? Also, why would the image name 'red' be hard-coded in? I would like it to pick this value up from the database column for each record. Also, how will this change the image in ID 'ImageView00'? Was I supposed to plug 'ImageView00' in somewhere? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: you would need to do it within an activity or contentprovider to get a context.  Substitute the hard-coded red from your table query.  As for imageview that is just an example ... depends what you really want to do, it wasn't clear from the question.  Anything beyond that is beyond the scope of this question.  You can't simply cut'n'paste code, you'll never get far if you don't learn the platform you're developing for ... http://developer.android.com

Comment: Thanks. I have leaned the platform (have 2 apps so far), but db items are very new to me an I'm still in the early learning stages...and confused at present. I posted my code so I thought that was where I was supposed to add yours (sorry for my confusion). Would you mind explaining how ImageView00 can pick this data up using your code? I think that might clarify things for me. The other answer was closer on that point, but if/else statements wouldn't work for this. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated but I feel your not applying much thought to this and asking for help because it's easier than trying.  I have given you benefit of the doubt and provided you with an updated version of the example.  Please note that I'm using the color name instead of the image name as they appear to be the same but you can substitute the value you require.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I think with what you provided I'll be able to get this figured out. I am sorry to hear that you think that re: 'easier than typing'. I can assure you that I spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out on my own before I posted my question. I wasn't looking for an easy shortcut...just help with confusion that I wasn't able to resolve on my own. I apologize that my confusion seemed otherwise to you. I really do appreciate you sticking with this and providing me with help. I will mark your answer up and and check it as answered. Thanks again.

Comment: Well that's why I gave you the benefit of the doubt ... sometimes the more you stare at it the more confusing it all seems. Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. If I had to do it myself I would save the images as Blob in the database. Straight forward and easy to use.
The other alternative is to use if - else if - else if like this:

```
ImageView imageview = findViewById(R.id.ImageView00);
    if( colorname.equals("Red") )
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
    else if( colorname.equals("Red") )
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can see how this would actually change the ImageView00 field, but there are 100's of records so that would make for a really long if/else stmt. Rather than evaluating the field with an if/else stmt, I'd like it to pull the image file name from the db and display that image. Would you know how I could do that? Any help appreciated. Thanks. [P.S. The images are not saved in the db as Blob. They are files in the res/drawable directory. Multiple records may use the same image so it seems better to have the image file there just 1x than saving it multiple times in the db]

Comment: Since you have more than 100 records, my response is a no go. Okay another alternative is to use HashMap<>. Use the colorsName for keys and ids for values. Then iterate the HashMap<> to find every id corresponding to a colorname. <br> By the way you could design your database in such way you only have to save an image only once. Just created another table for the images, and link the tables for colors to it.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this alternative as a possibility. Also, that is a great idea re: database design. I will mark your answer up. Thanks again!